# Formik and FieldArray Mapping with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am new to React and Formik and still trying to learn how to use it.  I am trying to map items from an array of items.  However, I am not sure what the proper syntax is for the mapping.  I get the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

This is the InitialValues:

```
{
    "costs": [{
        "cost_Id": 1,
        "investment_Plan_Id": 1,
        "item": "abc",
        "amount": "3",
        "unit_Cost": "444"
    }, {
        "cost_Id": 2,
        "investment_Plan_Id": 1,
        "item": "xyz",
        "amount": "4",
        "unit_Cost": "99"
    }, {
        "cost_Id": 3,
        "investment_Plan_Id": 1,
        "item": "fff",
        "amount": "33",
        "unit_Cost": "5435"
    }]
}
```

Below is the code with items not mapped properly:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";
import axios from 'axios';

const App: React.FC = () => {

    const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();

    async function getInitialValues() {
        try {

             return await axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:53132/api/Projects/1",
            })
                .then((response: any) => {

                //console.log(response);

                const initialValues = {
                    Costs: response.data.costs
                }

                console.log(initialValues);

                return initialValues;

            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getInitialValues().then(res => setInitialValues(res));

        return () => {
            //console.log(initialValues);
        };

    }, []);

    const handleOnSubmit = (values: any, actions: { setSubmitting: (arg0: boolean) => void; resetForm: () => void; }) => {
        console.log(values)
    };

    return initialValues ? (

            <Formik initialValues={initialValues}
                    onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>

                    {props => (

                        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>

                            <FieldArray

                                {...props.values.costs.map((method: { name: any}, index: any) => (

                                    <div key={index}>
                                        <input
                                            name={`costs.${index}.item`}
                                            value={method.name}
                                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                                        />

                                    </div>

                                ))}

                            />

                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    )}

            </Formik>

    ) : <span>loading...</span>;

}

export default App;
```

Comment: In the API response handler, you have `Costs: response.data.costs` instead of `costs: response.data.costs`. (Notice the capital C).  Is that just a typo in the question, or in your actual code?

Comment: I replaced the code to use costs: response.data.costs.  The error is gone, but the field does not render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `name` and `render` props for the `FieldArray` component.  You also had a typo while setting `Costs` instead of `costs`.

```
const renderFieldArray = (props: FormikProps<any>) => (arrayHelpers: any) => {
  return props.values.costs.map((x, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <input
          name={`costs.${index}.item`}
          value={method.name}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  });
};

<FieldArray name="costs" render={renderFieldArray(props)} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the example snippet. I get this error when using the snippet: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions".

Comment: @TerryDoll, you might need to remove the `arrayHelpers` variable if you're not using it.

Comment: I added: "arrayHelpers: any", but I am getting this error: "Cannot find name 'props'."  I suspect that is because the initialValues are async?

Comment: @TerryDoll, I updated the answer to pass the props.

Comment: Thanks for the revised code.  I tried it, but getting the following error: "Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: @TerryDoll, you're going to need to add the necessary `FormikProps<any>` type.

Comment: I added ": any" after each argument and updated "value={x.item}" and it works!  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What's the type of `arrayHelpers`? Adding `any` is anti-pattern and in fact lint is usually set up to prohibit it.